# {"error":"Content-Type header [] is not supported","status":406} When Inserting Data to Elasticsearch with Golang

Tags: elasticsearch, go, header, content-type

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

I use Golang to insert data into elasticsearch, but it seems that there is no data inserted because of this error.

> {"error":"Content-Type header [] is not supported","status":406}

I already set the content type. Note that I use elasticsearch 6.4.3

```
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", urlSearch, bytes.NewBuffer(query))
            request.Close = true
            request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

Last but not least, I use elastigo package to make requests to elasticsearch.

Comment: Have you tried after remove "request.Close = true" this line?

Comment: github.com/olivere/elastic is easy to use to make requests to Elasticsearch, maybe you could take a look at that instead of writing your own client

Comment: The error says "Content-Type header is not supported". Have you tried not sending the Content-Type header?

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange response, as it suggests that this line:

```
request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

Failed to add the value to the key slice.  In modern go that does not happen, e.g.

```
data := []byte(`{"a":1}`)
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "", bytes.NewBuffer(data))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
req.Header.Set("Foo", "Bar")
fmt.Printf("%v\n", req.Header)
```

Prints

```
map[Foo:[Bar]]
```

See [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eZU_qG3YDWG).

Are you using older version of Go that doesn't match that behavior?  (I'm on 1.11.2 locally.)

Five suggestions:

(1) Handle the `err` return value from NewRequest to verify there's no problem there (see example above).

(2) Print the request `Header` value before send to verify it looks right at that point (see example above).

(3) Try [the `Add` method](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Add) for the Content-Type header instead of `Set` as an alternative:

```
func (h Header) Add(key, value string)
```

(4) Verify that you're not going through a proxy that strips header values.

(5) Verify that "application/json" is an acceptable content type for the endpoint you're hitting, as the empty value in the error response could be erroneous itself.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already try your options from 1 to 3. As for no. 4, I am not sure that it has something to do with the proxy. For no.5, I don't know whether "application/json" is acceptable content type for elasticsearch. I use elasticsearch 6.4.3 where it won't accept string anymore. Instead, it uses Text to replace string as the data type. Do you have any idea?